# Как создать массив дом элементов?

Tags: jquery, массивы, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток. Есть список

```
<ul>
    <li class="i"></li>
    <li class="i"></li>
    <li class="i"></li>
    <li class="i"></li>
</ul>
```

Как поместить пункты списка в массив через js, а потом вывести все содержимое каждого из списка?

Comment: [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/NodeList) не подойдет ?

Comment: не, мне надо создать массив из всех li

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я так и не понял, что конкретно вам надо заполучить в массив, поэтому перечислю несколько вариантов:

```
var li = $('.i');
// получаем содержимое списков (данные внутри тегов)
var vals = li.map(function(){
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
console.log(vals);
// получаем элементы, как объекты
var objs = li.map(function(){
    return this;
}).get();
console.log(objs);
// получаем html-код элементов со всем содержимым
var htmls = li.map(function(){
    return $(this).prop('outerHTML');
}).get();
console.log(htmls);
```

[Смотрим работу на примере](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/z2dN6/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var liArray = document.getElementsByClassName('i');
var liContainArr = [];
for(var i=0; i<liArray.length; i++){
    liContainArr[i] = liArray[i].innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: liArray лучше так не называть, т.к. это NodeList а не Array (невозможна итерация используя `for (key in liArray){}`  )